# Power of simple linear regression when the independent variable is correlated with the true causal variable

Tags: regression, causality, statistical-power, bioinformatics

Consider the simple linear regression model:

\begin{align*}
    y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon
\end{align*}

Let $b_1$ be the least squares estimate of $\beta_1$, 
assuming the variance of error $\sigma ^2$ is known,
then we have:

\begin{align*}
    \sigma ^2(b_1) &= \frac{\sigma ^2}{S_{xx}} \\
    \sigma(b_1) &= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{S_{xx}}}
\end{align*}

Define $\Delta$ as $\frac{\beta_1 - 0}{\sigma(b_1)}$, 
we then calculate the power as follows (I am not sure
about this, but I put my thoughts here):

\begin{align*}
    Power
    &= P\left(\frac{b_1 - 0}{\sigma(b_1)} > Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right)
     + P\left(\frac{b_1 - 0}{\sigma(b_1)} < - Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right) \\
    &= P\left(\frac{b_1 - \beta_1}{\sigma(b_1)} > -\frac{\beta_1}{\sigma(b_1)} + Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right)
     + P\left(\frac{b_1 - \beta_1}{\sigma(b_1)} < -\frac{\beta_1}{\sigma(b_1)} - Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right) \\
    &= \Phi\left(  \Delta - Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right) 
     + \Phi\left(- \Delta - Z_{1 - \alpha / 2}\right)
\end{align*}

Suppose instead of $x$ (which we see here as the true causal variable), 
we have $x^*$, which is correlated with $x$
by $r$, how should we evaluate the power? 
Do we need more information other than $r$?

There is a popular and insightful saying that goes "all models are 
wrong, some are useful", but please note that here we are assuming
the model is actually **perfectly right**, and there is a true causal relationship
between $x$ and $y$, then move forward to consider the case where we don't 
know the causal variable and only have $x^*$ at hand.

Comment: You cannot quantify the power until you have proposed a specific and quantitative alternative model.  *All* discussions of power occur (necessarily) within such a context.  Unfortunately, "correlated with $x$ by $r$" is too indeterminate to be of use.  For instance, $x^{*}$ could be $y$ itself!

Comment: Could you please give an example of such an alternative model?

Comment: One alternative is $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2+\varepsilon.$  This is often used for checking linearity. It is almost never proposed as a "perfectly right" or even a realistic model--but by comparing the two models and finding that the data are more likely in the alternative model than the original, we have some evidence that the original is *not* very good (we conclude its fit is bad). Obviously there are many other possible alternatives, depending on *how* the fit could deviate from linearity. (Your question seems to assume the alternative $y=\beta_0+\varepsilon$.)

Comment: I am asking this question because this scenario arises in Genome Wide Association studies, very much in the mode in today's genetics. We have chips for getting genotype info at different spots of DNA over the whole genome, but we don't need all of them, because in every small region there are those highly linked (correlated) spots, thus for every such region we only pick one spot, to save time and money.

Comment: The theory is that if one of the spots is related to a disease, then even if we only have info on another spot nearby, we should be able to detect that this region is related to the disease through that other spot which is included in our testing chip. This is intuitive, but not at all rigorous. I tried to find out an explanation in the literature with no avail. I am thinking this could be the topic of an interesting paper. But maybe someone has published something somewhere not so easy to find.